# Image repeating itself on iPhone Safari browser

Tags: html, css

Image repeating itself on iPhone Safari browser.
It works properly when I test on my computer.

[image]

```css
#banner {
  padding: 6em 0 4em 0 ;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex; }
  #banner h1 {
    margin-top: -0.125em; }
  #banner .content {
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    width: 50%; }
  #banner .image {
    -moz-flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-grow: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 4em;
    width: 50%; }
    #banner .image img {
      height: 100%;
      -moz-object-fit: cover;
      -webkit-object-fit: cover;
      -ms-object-fit: cover;
      object-fit: cover;
      -moz-object-position: center;
      -webkit-object-position: center;
      -ms-object-position: center;
      object-position: center;
      width: 100%; }

      @media screen and (max-width:751px) {
        #banner .image img{
          height: 110%;
          -moz-object-fit: contain;
      -webkit-object-fit: contain;
      -ms-object-fit: contain;
      object-fit: contain;
      -moz-object-position: center;
      -webkit-object-position: center;
      -ms-object-position: center;
      object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
    <div class="content">
        <header>
            <h1>Hi, I’m Tim,<br /> Your Next Software Engineer</h1>
            <p>Ready to Change The World?</p>
        </header>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><a class='button big' href='aboutme.html'>Meet Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="image object">
        <img src="images/headshot.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
</section>
```

I tried changing `contain` to `scale-down` but it also did not work on iPhone Safari browser.

I am a beginner developer and I have no idea how to resolve this, help me please.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Please make sure your snippet demonstrates the problem. E.g. include an image we can see and run it yourself as I can’t at first glance see where repetition would come from.

Comment: have you tried `background-repeat: no-repeat` on the img ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#banner {
  padding: 6em 0 4em 0 ;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex; }
  #banner h1 {
    margin-top: -0.125em; }
  #banner .content {
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    width: 50%; }
  #banner .image {
    -moz-flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-grow: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 4em;
    width: 50%; }
    #banner .image img {
      height: 100%;
      -moz-object-fit: cover;
      -webkit-object-fit: cover;
      -ms-object-fit: cover;
      object-fit: cover;
      -moz-object-position: center;
      -webkit-object-position: center;
      -ms-object-position: center;
      object-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%; }

      @media screen and (max-width:751px) {
        #banner .image img{
          height: 110%;
          -moz-object-fit: contain;
      -webkit-object-fit: contain;
      -ms-object-fit: contain;
      object-fit: contain;
      -moz-object-position: center;
      -webkit-object-position: center;
      -ms-object-position: center;
      object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
    <div class="content">
        <header>
            <h1>Hi, I’m Tim,<br /> Your Next Software Engineer</h1>
            <p>Ready to Change The World?</p>
        </header>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><a class='button big' href='aboutme.html'>Meet Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="image object">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573496359142-b8d87734a5a2" alt="" />
    </span>
</section>
```

add `background-repeat: no-repeat` property in  `#banner .image img`